# What word (or phrase) describes someone who is cheap with other people but spends extravagantly on themselves?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word in English that describes a person who is extremely cheap with other people but spends extravagantly on themselves?

For example, I know someone who expects everyone else to pay the bill for him when we go out and will buy birthday gifts at the dollar store. But he wears designers clothes, has the newest iPhone, and drives a luxury car.

I know there are many words that describe people who are frugal with their money (cheap, scrooge, miserly, cheapskate, etc.), but they seem to cover all spending habits, and not distinguish between spending on other people versus spending for oneself.

The closest I can find is just "selfish" or I would have to describe it as a phrase "he is cheap with everyone but himself".

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know such a word or phrase, but you might make up a sarcastic one: "He's really generous, when it comes to himself."